# Find and remove first child element from all HTML files

Tags: html, regex, dom, sublimetext3, dreamweaver

I would like to know how/if I can use any code editor (like Brackets, Sublime or Dreamweaver) to find and remove the first child element.

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="parent-item">
   <h3>I need to be removed</h3>
   <p>But I need to stay here</p>
   <h3>I need to stay too</3>
  ......
</div>
```

So how can I find and remove the first h3 tag from the following example?

Comment: You better use a parser to proceed, regex are not the right tool to play with html tags.

Comment: I would try this with Notepadd++ and the TextFX plugin. With this plugin you can find/replace using regex. http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can try the replace with regex  find and replace all  just check that is the only h3 element   to avoid other deletion or go next and skip for someone you don't want to delete

here is the regex

```
 /<h3>[a-zA-Z0-9].+/g
```

Comment: Your example doesn't really work in my context because it will delete all the h3 tags in the document.

Answer (score 0):

hi make it simple,

```
.parent-item h3:first-child{ display:none;}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write an answer to this question. It is always a good idea to write a few words of explanation in addition to any code you put in your answer. It is especially helpful to explain why and how your code solves the initial problem. You can easily [edit] your answer to add this explanation, I suggest you do so. This will help OP and anybody else with the same question to understand your answer.